# How to query from three tables in php?

Tags: php

Table 1: Listings
- listing_id (auto increment)
- dealer_id
- vehicle_title
- location_id
- category_id

Table 2: Locations
- location_id
- location

Table 3: Category
- category_id
- category

How can I get all listings with the location (from Locations Table) and category (from Category Table).

Comment: You can't with PHP. Do you mean HTML tables?

Comment: @Neal What? Im pretty sure you missed what he is asking. You absolutely **CAN** query and join tables in PHP. Question gets a downvote anyway for being so broad.

Comment: @Neal Are you trolling me? lol. You must be.

Comment: @Wobbles PHP has no notion of "tables" that I know of. Maybe you are thinking of [tag:html] or [tag:mysql]?

Comment: @Neal SQL tables, but he is querying them in PHP, pretty sure he is looking for help in his query string. As i said ques gets a down vote for being poorly written.

Answer (score 1):

This is only the query to take information from 3 tables

```
Select * from Listings,Locations,Category where Listings.location_id = Locations.location_id and Listings.category_id = Category.category_id ;
```

The full example of taking information from 2 tables are like that

```
$Attendance = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM Temp,Student where Temp.SID = Student.SID ";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $Attendance [$row['SID']] = array ("SID" => $row['SID'] , "CID" =>  $row['CID'] , "SName" => $row['SName'] , "TDate" => $row['TDate'] );   
}

foreach ($Attendance as $i) 
{
    echo "".$i['SID'];
}
```

This will print to you the SID values .

You have to try the query at first if it work then continue withe code .

Comment: Try this it should work .

Comment: This is not [tag:php]